# FileNotFoundError even with filemode "a+"

Tags: python, file

I have code that looks like this:

```
logPath = os.path.join(os.path.normpath(os.getcwd()) + "/datei.log") + os.sep
logFile = open(logPath, "a+")
logFile.write(foo)
logFile.close()
```

This *should* open the file `./datei.log` (or create it if it doesn't exist). However, I get a `FileNotFoundError`:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/foo/bar/datei.log/'
```

All resources I have seen indicate that `"a+"` instead of `"a"` should fix this, but this clearly fails. How can I resolve it?

Comment: You may want to drop the trailing `+ os.sep` from the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function expects a path-like object that points to a file in an existing directory. When the directory does not exist an error is raised, in my case in Python 3.6 the error is:

> NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/grr/datei.log/'

As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ pointed out the trailing `os.sep` adds a '/' at the end of your file descriptor making it appear to be a path instead of a file. This is what is causing the error.

Comment: Exactly you can see that even with:
`logFile = open(logPath, "w")`
You get the same error